# iOS video toolbox gives "Ignoring enqueueSampleBuffer: because status is "failed""

Tags: ios8, cmsamplebuffer

I am using video toolbox in iOS8 to play an h264 stream along with a PCM audio stream. Video is displayed fine as long as I dont start the audio stream. As soon as I call AudioQueueStart, all enqueueSampleBuffer calls stop displaying video and prints the error  "Ignoring enqueueSampleBuffer: because status is "failed"".

There are no errors returned from CMBlockBuffer calls. enqueueSampleBuffer doesnt return anything and hence I cant write a code to recreate video layer again on this error.

This only happens on iOS device and not on simulator. Audio and video plays perfectly fine on Simulator. I run Audio and Video on separate threads such that one doesnt block the other. Has anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was happening because I had the mute switch on iphone turned ON.
I used AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback for my audio session to overcome this.
This problem is resolved.